# Cannot launch KDE Plasma in Wayland - wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa

Tags: kde, wayland

### The problem:

Whenever I choose `Plasma (Wayland)` in SDDM, it stalls for a solid minute and boots me out to the login screen again. I cannot launch KDE Plasma in Wayland, and have determined that this is the cause of the problem:

```
$ kwin_wayland --xwayland
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, dxcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb, wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa.
```

Curiously, `wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa` is listed *twice* in the list of available platform plugins.

### I have tried the following:

- Reinstalling `qtwayland5` and `qt6-wayland`

  - This would be if `wayland` was not listed in the available platform plugins
- Using the prefix `QT_QPA_PLATFORMS="wayland;wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa;xcb"`

  - The list of selected platforms is still `""`
- Using a few other XDG variables

### System

**Distro:** Kubuntu 23.04
**KDE Plasma:** 5.27.6
**KDE Frameworks:** 5.107.0
**Qt Version:** 5.15.8
**Kernel:** 6.2.0-23-generic (64-bit)

### Notes

- I am using the `lunar` and `jammy` Ubuntu repositories, as well as the KDE Backports PPA.
- I have an AMD GPU, but no drivers for it installed. Intel Mesa GPU drivers only.

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help.